# How to use data from Python for Weka?

Tags: python, weka

I've installed weka and the python-weka-wrapper.

I got as far as

```
from weka.classifiers import Classifier
clf=Classifier(classname="weka.classifiers.rules.JRip")

from random import randint
X = [[randint(1,10) for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(100)]
y = [randint(0,1) for _ in range(100)]
```

but now I don't know how to load my data which is available as a Python data structure.

How can I load my data matrices, output the rules (in some parsable format) and test the classifier on new data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create data on the fly, by defining the structure (ie attributes) and then adding the data rows. Also, I added a convenience method to instantiate Instances to the `weka.core.dataset` module called `create_Instances_from_lists`, which is scheduled for the next release.
This question has been [answered](https://groups.google.com/forum/https://groups.google.com/forum/?nomobile=true#!topic/python-weka-wrapper/yHOi0AsFf8E) on the project's mailing list as well, including examples and pointers.